# Turn Android into USB host

Tags: android, arduino, usb

My exploration here comes from a recent Arduino project.

I have an old(ish) Android LG Tribute. I removed the broken screen so now the device is missing visual output. I have rooted it and can control it from shell commands and other ways.

I want to write an application for the device to communicate over usb.

Basically what I want to accomplish:

Plug in USB cord to android. Press button on cord plugged into android device -> Snap picture with devices camera - Output data in visual blinks via LED programmed blink logic for debug.

I feel I should be able to handle nearly everything on the device. I just need to know where to begin looking for Android USB output and input programming.

Basically want to use my android as a microcontroller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Arduinos for this very application, such as the Arduino Mega ADK (Accessory Development Kit): https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMegaADK

For other Arduinos, a USB host shield can be used that's compatible with the ADK: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoUSBHostShield

Details for the Android-side development and the ADK in general are available here: http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will begin researching whether or not my device is compatible with ADK. I have an Arduino Uno R3 (clone). The USB Host Shield you mentioned is the link I have been looking for! Regards,